# how to exclude a service from HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule angular?

Tags: angular, httpclient, angular-services, angular-pipe, angular-in-memory-web-api

I have HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule already configured on my angular application. I want to exclude a service, so I can test it without adding the base url in the first: 
Problem:

**app.module.ts :**

```
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemHeroService, { rootPath: '/api/'})
  ],
```

**serviceToExclude.service.ts :**

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceToExcludeService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { };

  loadUsers(searchValue: string): Observable<Users> {
    const url: string = 'http://localhost:4000/users?q=' + searchValue;

    return this.http.get<Users>(url).pipe(
        map(response => {
            return (<Users>response)
        }),
        catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

Link called is : **https://localhost/api/http://localhost:4000/users?q=h**

and not : **http://localhost:4000/users?q=h**

**So my Question how to exclude this service from heriting previous base URL ???**

Answer (score 0):

Add passThrUnknownUrl:
app.module.ts :

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemHeroService, { 
        rootPath: '/api/',
        passThruUnknownUrl: true
    })
],
```